add rubberbanding bounce overscroll on desktop firefox
questions about overscroll usually ask how to disable it on a mobile web page. I want to do the opposite: create a rubber banding effect on all web pages while browsing on the desktop. I'm using either the space bar, page down or mouse wheel to scroll.
I tried html { overscroll-behavior: contain; overflow: scroll } on Firefox. Don't know what else to do.

To create a rubber banding effect on all web pages while browsing on the desktop, you can try the following approach:
use the CSS property "overflow: scroll; "on the body tag of your web page. This will enable both horizontal and vertical scrolling.
Apply the CSS property
"over scroll- behavior: contain; "to the body tag. This property controls the behavior when the user attempts to scroll beyond the content boundaries.
Here`s an example of how you can apply these CSS properties to achieve the desired effect:
CSS
copy
body {
overflow: scroll;
over scroll - behavior: contain.
}
make sure to apply there CSS properties to the appropriate selector in your CSS file or style section.
It`s worth mooting that the over scroll behavior may vary across different browsers and platforms. While "over scroll- behavior" is supported in modern browsers, not all browsers may support it, and the behavior may differ. Therefore, it's essential to test your implementation across various browser's to ensure consistent results.
If the above approach doesn`t work as expected, you can consider using JavaScript to handle the scrolling behavior. By detecting the scroll event and adjusting the scroll position, you can create a custom rubber banding effect. However, keep in mind that this approach may require more advanced coding and may not be as straightforward as using CSS properties.
I hope this helps you achieve the desired rubber banding effect on your web pages while browsing on the desktop.

Your post sounds like it's written by an AI, but the grammar is so off that I am not sure. But I already tried that.
